# For "onevent change" in javascript I am trying to access the parameter of the function, but getting an error as "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have a code as below:

```
<input type="text" id="GAMES" name="OwnGames" width="100%" onChange="ValidateText(document.getElementById('GAMES'))";
```

Javascript:

```
function ValidateText(e,Games) {
    console.log(Games.id);
    var text_value=e.target.value;
    console.log(text_value);
 }
```

Console logs is correctly giving event e, but giving an error as **Games is undefined.**

After removing argument Games, I am getting an error as **e is undefined.**

Comment: You're passing `'GAMES'` only, pass `event` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

We have an easy way to access all the element property and values. Please refer the snippet.

```js
function ValidateText(event) {
    var text_value= event.target.value;
    var id = event.target.id;
    console.log(`value : ${text_value},  id : ${id}`)
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="GAMES" name="OwnGames" width="100%" onChange="ValidateText(event)" >
```